# Laravel : sending data from one page to second to third to submit in DB

Tags: laravel, forms, routes

Need to send data from 1 -> 2 (Add more info) -> 3 (Preview & Submit).

First page user submit a url in an input

Second page user submit the url related information like Title, Description, Selects a category, add tags etc. All in inputs and textarea.

Third page for final view of submitted information so far and submit it into the DB.

But the sedon pae won't go to third page it gives POST error.

Controller

```
public function submitUrl(Request $request)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'link' => 'required|unique:links|min:5|active_url',
    ]);
    $categories = DB::table('categories')->get();
    return view('submit2')->with('validatedData', $validatedData)->with('categories', $categories);


}
public function submitData(Request $request)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required|between:15,150',
        'category' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required|between:250,500',
        'tags' => ['required'],
    ]);
    $categories = DB::table('categories')->get();
    return $validatedData;
    return view('submit3')->with('validatedData', $validatedData)->with('categories', $categories);


}

public function saveData(Request $request)
{


}
```

Route

```
Route::get('/submit', 'SubmitLinks@index')->middleware('auth');
Route::post('/submit2', 'SubmitLinks@submitUrl')->middleware('auth');
Route::post('/submit3', 'SubmitLinks@submitData')->middleware('auth');
```

Comment: What is the POST error?

Comment: The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.

Answer (score 0):

Your first route is defined as:

```
Route::get('/submit', 'SubmitLinks@index')->middleware('auth');
```

and I believe you are using it to save first step data via POST. So change its method to post then like so:

```
Route::post('/submit', 'SubmitLinks@index')->middleware('auth');
```